# Jquery Toggle visibility button

Tags: jquery, html, button, toggle, visibility

Im trying to make a button which should make one element hiding (display: none;) and one visible and vice versa.

Here is an example of the sort of thing ive got:

[example](http://www.ventique.co.uk/product_pages/natural/kesav_white.html)

at the moment when clicking 'technical details' it changes display: none; to display: block; on an element. I now need to make the element under it to be hidden when this one is shown...

Here is the code im using...

```
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "Technical Details";
}
else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "Product Information";
}
}
```

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance...

Comment: What about posting related `html`?

Comment: And if you're using jQuery, why aren't you *using* it? Or is that tag a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you wrap your 2 different text html elements in a span and give them and your links a class called "togglePrdctAndTech". set the default hidden ones to display:none; then you can toggle them in your function like this

```
function toggleElements(){
  $(".togglePrdctAndTech").toggle();
}
```